# Psycopg2 can't connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I've set up a PostgreSQL database running on Docker and am currently trying to get psycopg2-binary to run a script to create tables in the PostgreSQL db. I  keep getting this error and I  don't know/understand what to do next. Please help!

My script:

```py
import psycopg2
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

HOST = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST")
USER = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER")
PASSWORD = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
DATABASE = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB")
PORT = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT")

class Connection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=DATABASE,
            user=USER,
            password=PASSWORD,
            host=HOST,
            port=PORT
        )

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

Error:

```
File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Comment: If Postgres is running in docker, you won't be able to connect through a socket.  What is the value of POSTGRES_HOST?  It shouldn't be localhost.

Comment: @Jeremy The value of POSTGRES_HOST  is shown below.

```
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=nba
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

Comment: Is the script running in the same Docker container?  Can you connect to the database using `psql`? Is the `HOST` really `postgres` and if so is that mapping to `local`(socket)?. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @Jeremy, it is actually trying to connect to `local` not `localhost`, otherwise the error would be like: `Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) ...`